# Kivy: Is there a way to add label by pressing button

Tags: python, button, kivy, label, addition

I want to know, if there is a way to add label(or anything else like checkbox, button etc.) by pressing button.

Comment: Hey there, I would like you to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and go through [how do I ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and make the necessary changes. Its always a good practice to show your research so far and work related to the question if necessary as opposed to asking the community to write the code based on your requirement.

Comment: Further to @AST's answer: yes it is possible and a normal thing to do that is well described by the documentation. If you have a problem, this makes it doubly important to provide an example as we don't know what part of it you have an issue with.